# Is there a "most trusted" translation for the Pirkei Avot - ethics of our fathers?

Tags: jewish-books, translation, pirke-avot-ethicsof

I always seem to have this issue when choosing Jewish texts. I never know if certain books are more trusted than others. I was curious if there was a version of the Pirkei Avot that is considered the most reliable in terms of English translation.

I know that certain translations sometimes lose a bit of the meaning rooted in the Hebrew so I'm curious if there's a standard which is considered a "most trusted" within the category.

I appreciate your help, thank you!

- Seeing a Hebrew/English hybrid translation.
- This would be for group study at the local shul.
- I'm a beginner to intermediary level learner on the subject.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm not sure if this question may be voted as being "opinionated". There are so many translations around and many of them are good and "trustworthy". It all depends on your knowledge, learning level, as well as what "angle" you're seeking. I recommend that you narrow down your question including some of these factors. I think you will get better answers this way.

Comment: @DanF Just made the edits, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artscroll is always a good choice when it comes to classic Jewish literature translated to English; they are possibly the most famous Orthodox Jewish publisher out there. [Here](http://artscroll.com/search/pirkei%20avos.aspx) is a link to that. They have a selection of different formats and additions, but  I believe the translation is more or less the same between each one.

Another good translation is from [Kehot](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=EO-PIRK.DEL), the central Lubavitch publisher.

Comment: Are you aware of any major differences or distinctions between the Artscroll version and the Kehot version?

Comment: @Avri - No, they're very much the same. ArtScroll's is older though.

Comment: What about the translation of R. Jonathan Sacks published by Koren?